# Shippo cost on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, shippo

we are thinking in using Shippo for our shipping but would like to have the shipping rates of Shippo at the product page and also the checkout.

How could we do that or what alternatives do we have?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find either of the following plugins for Magento 1.9 helpful for getting rates for multiple carriers through Shippo:

- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shippo.html -- the official Shippo Magento App
- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/offer-cheap-shipping-rates-to-your-customers.html -- we know the Build-A-Team team so free to email Shippo's support team if you'd like to get in touch, and we can point you the right way.